# Are there places where I can sell items for a higher price than the merchants?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Is there possibly a shop where I can sell materials and food for a higher price than regular merchants like Beetle? Or do they all offer the same prices?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no shop per se, but there are people that will buy your things for more money.  This is not an exhaustive list, but any means, but some examples are...

- Fireproof Lizards can be sold to a guy in the mines to the south of Goron City.  He'll first give you an item, and then will buy three lizards at a double-cost rate to what you sell them for to merchants.
- There's a guy in one of the stables that will buy your Gourmet Meat at 100 a pop, though you can only sell to him a few times a day.
- A Gerudo woman in Goron City will buy a random type of gem in batches of 10 for 200 rupees more than their normal sale price. However, you don't know which gems she'll ask for.

Comment: Do you by chance know which stable?

Comment: @Batophobia I believe it's the first stable if you exit the starting area going west.

Comment: @Batophobia it's actually the stable on the castle zone. The man you can find walking just in front of the stable during day time will only buy 3 pices of XXL meat for 100 rupies each, after this you can rest on a campfire and repeat the proces.

Comment: The stable in question is [Outskirt Stable](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Outskirt%20Stable).

Answer (score 8):

There is a Gerudo who walks around the Goron town. She buys gems at a rate higher than a shop, in chunks of 10 at a time. If you have a fair amount of gems, she's a great npc to visit.

Comment: To specify, she'll buy them for 200 more than a shop would. So 10 Rubies go for 2100, she'll buy them for 2300.

Comment: She's also very picky with what gems she'll buy, and is therefore not very reliable. The gems she wants changes every time you sell her gems. It's possible it also changes every day, though I'm not 100% certain about that.

Comment: @Nolonar it changes every day, once per day. She states that herself.

Answer (score 5):

I know of two other NPCs that will trade items for rupees.

- In Rito Village, there is a lady who will buy baked apples from you. The more baked apples you give her, the more rupees you get per apple. Apples are fairly common, and you can bake up to 10 at a time if you have access to Death Mountain.
- In the stable just before the entrance to the Gerudo Desert, there is a man who will buy 55 Rushrooms from you for 330 rupees (by comparison, most merchants pay 165 for the same amount).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this one has been mentioned yet, and correct me if it doesn't really fit the OP's questions, but after you complete a certain quest in Zora's Domain, you can trade 10 Luminous Stones to a guy for 1 diamond which sells for 500. Luminous Stones only sell for 30 each so that's a pretty good deal. And it's something that can be repeated forever, as long as you can find a good supply of stones.

Comment: Lum stones sell for 70 not 30. 70x10 is 700 so not the best option if you want rupees lol. But if you're after diamonds that sounds like a good deal!